# A question on c program language

Tags: c

i want print a statement 5 times

without using any loop
n should be in a line

Comment: It isn't clear what you want, or why you don't want to use a loop. Please edit your question to provide an example.

Comment: Though I haven't been on SO long, this makes my top ten list of most poorly formatted questions.

Comment: If this is Homework, please use the [homework] tag.

Comment: @typoknig: you ain't seen nuthin' yet.

Comment: printf("a statement 5 times without using any loop n should be in a line");

This way?

Answer (score 7):

```
printf("%s %s %s %s %s",s,s,s,s,s);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
printf("%s",s);printf("%s",s);printf("%s",s);printf("%s",s);printf("%s",s);
```

It's 5 print statements on one line, and an alternative to the others who used a single print statement!

Answer (score 0):

Like this, you mean ?

```
const char * s = "a statement";

printf("%s %s %s %s %s\n", s, s, s, s, s);
```

Comment: NO NO NO That's *SIX* lines! OP said "should be in **a** line" (emphasis added) ;)

Comment: Yes, by "n" the OP seems to mean "and".